# How to put a right aligned link in jQuery tabs?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, append, jquery-tabs

I have three jQuery tabs on the left.
I wish to put a "Sign Out" link on the right within the tabs header.
How I can achieve that?

Comment: Do people have to sing a song to get out of your applications?  ;-)

Comment: That would have been an original idea I believe. Corrected now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use jQuery tabs, but could you do something like this within the header?

`<a href="" style="position:absolute; right:0">My link</a>`

Comment: The question is more about how to "append" it to the tabs header. And which is the selector to find out the tab header. Something like $('.ui-widget-header') I guess.

Comment: I get what you're saying. So the HTML for the tabs is being generated, and you don't know the proper selector. What browser are you using? Most seem to have some ability to view the HTML as it is updated. IE8, Firefox with Firebug, Safari, etc.

Comment: I simply have added a new tab and managed to right align it.

    <li style="float: right"><a href="#tab-logout" title="Logout">Logout</a></li>

Thanks anyway for your help.

Comment: @GadDLord You asked for the tab header selector. Actually, the tab header gets many classes assigned to it: `ui-tabs-nav`, `ui-helper-reset`, `ui-helper-clearfix`, `ui-widget-header` and `ui-corner-all`. More details about this under the Theming tab here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the delay,

What you are looking for is this :

```
<li style="float: right"><a href="yourlogoutlink"><span>Log out</span></a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is old and there is already an accepted answer but it came up near the top on a Google search that involves something similar and I have a much easier solution now that I figured I would share for others that find this question.

In your .cshtml or .aspx file, define the tabs like so:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
     <li><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tab3">Tab 3</a></li>
     <a href="/Account/SignOut" style="float:right;">Sign Out</a>
  </ul>
  <div id="tab1">tab 1 content</div>
  <div id="tab2">tab 2 content</div>
  <div id="tab3">tab 3 content</div>
</div>
```

If you try to validate the raw html, you will get an error for including the a tag as a direct child of the ul but, once you call the jQueryUi tabs function on the parent div, it will all get sorted the way you want and look